# How to find a hyperlink from within a Class

Tags: asp.net, vb.net

I'm trying to create a class that will allow me to set any hyperlinks in my site to either take the user to the requested url or show a tooltip message (or something) letting them know that they don't have the proper profile type to view that link. In the Class I will have a LinkVerification sub that will take the following parameters from the hyperlink when it's clicked:

1. Link ID
2. Url
3. User Profile type ID (there are 5 profile types such as Trial, Admin, etc..)
4. List of Profile type ID's that are not allowed.

I had hoped that by sending the Hyperlink ID as a parameter that I would be able to use FindControl to either set the specific Hyperlink's NavigateURL and ToolTip members, but I have been unsuccessful so far. I'm not sure how to go about this task. If anyone can help it would be greatly appreciated! Maybe what I'm trying to do isn't possible? Here's what I have so far:

```
Public Class LinkRestriction
'Get the user's Profile Type and redirect them to the requested link if they are allowed to and be given a message if not.
Public Shared Sub LinkVerification(ByVal linkID As String, ByVal Url As String, ByVal ProfileType As Integer, ByVal DisAllowed As String)
    'Convert comma separated list to a List
    Dim varRestricted As List(Of String) = ConvertStringsToList(DisAllowed, ",")

    'Find the control to be verified
    [some code]        

    If Not varRestricted.Contains(ProfileType.ToString) Then
        'Populate Tooltip of link control with message letting user know he doesn't have sufficient permissions to view this link.
        [some code]
    Else
        'send user to the request link
        [some code]
    End If
End Sub

Public Shared Function ConvertStringsToList(items As String, separator As Char) As List(Of String)
    Dim list As New List(Of String)()
    Dim listItmes As String() = items.Split(separator)
    For Each item As String In listItmes
        list.Add(item)
    Next
    Return list
End Function
End Class
```

Comment: Unsucessful? How? What errors do you get? How do you know that you are unsucessful?

Comment: I think it would be better to have a variable which indicates whether the user has permission or not, then using a logical block within the view to render the anchor tag as necessary.

Comment: @FarhanAnam I just mean I can't get the FindControl to even be recognized in Visual Studio even though I have Imports System.Web.UI

Comment: Why can you not simply pass the Hyperlink or Linkbutton (whichever you're using) into your method instead of a string showing it's id? Then there would be no need to find it.

Comment: As an aside, why do you have `ConvertStringsToList`? That's the same as  `yourstring.Split(",").ToList()`

Comment: @Daniel Cook: I'm not entirely sure how passing the entire Hyperlink into the method would work, Daniel. But, your second suggestion rocks. Thanks! Took me a minute to realize I needed System.Linq to make that work.

Comment: @Daniel Cook: Do you mean, make the sub a function and dynamically create the hyperlink control and return it? Yeah, that might work.

Comment: @Wilock **No** You imply that you already have a hyperlink which is being clicked (though if you expect to handle it on a postback, should not be a hyperlink). Since you already know what you clicked, you can update your method signature to something like: `Public Shared Sub LinkVerification(ByVal link As Hyperlink, ...` Then there's no searching, just call it correctly and you can update `link` directly as needed.

Comment: @Daniel Cook: Ahhh! Okay, I get you. I'll give that a try and let you know how it goes. Thanks!